# Powershell, csv match a row and column to modify another column

Tags: powershell, csv

My problem is quite simple, I have a csv file with a format as such:

```
Client   Status       Goal       Project
A         Done         Done       Waiting
B         Finished     Done       Cancelled
C                      Waiting    Finished
D         Done         Done       Done
```

Now, my queestion is simple, I want for example, to update a value on the column 'Goal' that matches client 'B'

I know that I can do import-csv and using calculated properties modify a column, but I have no idea how can I modify a specific row on a column that matches another row in another column and that is my question. I want for example to change Waiting to Finished client C, or change cancelled to waiting on client B.

Comment: error on my example, not real headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that something like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'D:\clientprojects.csv'
($csv | Where-Object {$_.Client -eq 'C'}).Goal = 'Finished'
($csv | Where-Object {$_.Client -eq 'B'}).Project = 'Waiting'

#output on console
$csv

# write to new CSV file
$csv | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\clientprojects-updated.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

output on console:

> ```
> Client Status   Goal     Project 
> ------ ------   ----     ------- 
> A      Done     Done     Waiting 
> B      Finished Done     Waiting 
> C               Finished Finished
> D      Done     Done     Done
> ```

Comment: Thank you, now I know the syntax for the this . !